# How do I create a new user in Firebase in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am fairly new to Flutter and Firestore and I've been trying to follow Reed Barger's guide to build a social media app https://www.udemy.com/course/build-a-social-network-with-flutter-and-firebase
Everything is going okay till the method of creating a user in Firestore. Android studio underlines document with the error 'The method 'document' isn't defined for the type 'CollectionReference'.'
How do I go round this?

```
  createUserInFirestore() async {
    //1) To check if user exists in user's collection in database (according to their id)
    final GoogleSignInAccount user = googleSignIn.currentUser;
    final DocumentSnapshot docu = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').document(user.id).get();

    //2) If user doesn't exist, take them to create account page
    if (!docu.exists) {
      final username = await Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreateAccount()));

      //3)  get user name from create account and use it to create new user's document in user's collection
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').document(user.id).set({
        "id": user.id,
        "username": username,
        "photoUrl": user.photoUrl,
        "email": user.email,
        "displayName": user.displayName,
        "bio": "",
        "timestamp": timestamp
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: depending on the version of Firestore you are using, in the news versions document it become  doc, so change document to doc  :)

Comment: I'm using `cloud_firestore: ^2.2.0` . doc is okay but it still doesn't take me to the CreateAccount page.

Comment: because  your user is aleardy existe !

Comment: The user doesn't exist on the firebase console and even using a new gmail account still doesn't take me to the page.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of Firestore you are using, they have introduced a breaking change recently, instead of `document` they now use `doc`. They did this to keep it uniform across most if not all languages.

You can reference [FlutterFire](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/) for more information and guides.